# "Перед", "до", и "раньше"

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли разница между этими конструциями:

Я зайду к тебе перед собранием.

Я зайду к тебе до собрания.

Я зайду к тебе раньше (?) собрания.

Answer (score 3):

Есть разница.

Перед собранием - совсем незадолго до добрания, до собрания - в значении "не после", раньше собрания - так говорить не рекомендуется, так как до нелепости искажается смысл высказывания: я зайду раньше, чем зайдёт собрание

Answer (score 0):

Разница если и есть, то не слишком существенная.

Но при этом "раньше собрания" - это не совсем по-русски. "Раньше" обычно соединяет два события по форме "событие А было раньше события Б", собрание как событие - это еще ничего, а вот событие "я зайду к тебе" выражено глаголо и плохо сочетается с существительным "собрание".

Два первых варианта - номальные, разнича между предлогами "до" и "перед" (в значении времени), конечно есть, но в данном контексте не ощущается. "Перед" - это непосредственно перед, незадолго, а "до" - это раньше, в любое время. В наше случае это не критично.  Указанная разница может быть значима в конструкциях типа "это произошло до 1917-го года" и "это произошло перед 1917-го года". Тут - да, существенно.